# Rails の コメントの少なさについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

お世話になります。

Ruby on Rails の開発を始めて、少し経ちました。
StackOverFlow、Qiitaなど含めて、ネット上でソースコードを多くみてきましたが、
そのほとんどがコメントがありません。
ライブラリのオーバーライドもコメントが無く、困ることがあります。
そのため、メソッド名から推測して詳細は目を瞑るか、親クラスのメソッドのコードを探すか、２択になります。

確かに、コメントが無くても理解できるのが良いコードだと思いますが、無理やり無くしているように感じることも多いです。
Railsの開発は、コメントを無くすほうが良い、というような風潮がありますか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: > `ネット上でソースコードを多くみてきましたが、そのほとんどがコメントがありません。` というのは、主観的なものですか？

Comment: SOやQiitaだと主にアプリケーション側のコードだと思いますが、Railsやライブラリ自体のコードの話にも読めます。どのコードをどういう目的で読んだ時にそう感じたのか、具体的な例は出せますか

Comment: @PicoSushi はい、完全に主観的なものです。私はもともと Java アプリの保守をやっておりまして、コメントが無いことによる弊害を多く感じておりました。ただ、Ruby、引いてはMVCが初めてということもあって、自分の感覚と業界の認識が違うのか、ということを気にしておりました。

Comment: @suzukis 申し訳ありません。SO側のものは全体を通した感覚的なもので、具体的な例が出せません。Qiitaに関しては、https://qiita.com/semind/items/1166473535507ed1e22b　この記事あたりでそう感じました。

Comment: QiitaやSOの投稿者の方を乏しめるような捉えられ方をしてしまっているのであれば、申し訳ございません。少し古いRailsの案件を請け負って、改修をしておりますが、MVC上にコメントがまったく無く、少し影響が出ています。これは、業界全体がそういうものなのか、それとも元々請け負っていた開発側の保守に対する親切心や余裕がなかったのか、というところを気にしています。例えば、マージ作業の邪魔になるから削除するべき、といったことがあれば今後削除する、といった形で、自分の今後の向上に繋げたいと考えています。

Answer (score 4):

私の主観ではありますが、Ruby on Railsに限らず、Javaのコードであっても、それこそどんな言語やフレームワークであっても、StackOverflowやQiitaに直接書かれているコードはコメントが少ない傾向にあると思います。私自身もそういった所で載せるコードを作る場合は、積極的にコメントを書こうとすることはありません。これには妥当な理由があります。

まず、これらの所で書かれるコードは、問題の再現するためや説明するためのコードであって、なんらかの完成したプロダクトではなく、その断片の場合が多いです。優れた質問では、さらに最低限再現できるところまで落とし込んで書いてしまっていますので、あるがままでしかないコードとして、特にコメントを入れる必要性が無くなると思います。回答の方は、すでに本文に解説が書いています。コードは実際の動作確認用の補足に過ぎないからです。コード内に本文と同じことをコメントをしても冗長なだけになるでしょう。Qiitaの記事についても同様です。

Ruby on Railsを用いたプログラムがどのような傾向なのかを見るには、(実験的な断片等ではない)完成したプロダクトを見ないと何も言えないと思います。例えば、[Redmine](https://github.com/redmine/redmine)、[mastodon](https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon)、[GitLab CE](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce)等です。

さて、それらを踏まえての傾向ですが、結局、これまた主観的な意見になしまっているのですが、Ruby on Railsというレールに乗っている限りコメントを入れることはないと思われます。例えば、コントローラーのクラスは場所や名前や親クラスからなんというコントローラーのクラスなのかが自明です。また、標準的なルーティングではどのようなパスでどのメソッドを付かれるのかも自明であり、`show`や`index`などはわざわざ説明する必要性はないとなります。逆に、レールから外れる場合や、レール外の部分については、コメントが書かれる傾向があると思います。

ただ、プレジェクト毎の方針の違いは必ずあるでしょうし、オープンソースとクローズドなプロダクトではまた傾向が変わってくると思いますので、一概にはなんとも言えないと思います。Ruby on Rails以外でも、オープンソースですと、コメントが全くないというプロダクトも珍しくないですから。(あ、それ、俺の作った…)